# How to set up multiple customDomain for a single API Gateway

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless, serverless-plugins

I'm trying to serve my website via lambda function rather than having static files in S3, so I'm using serverless and aws-serverless-express. I have a single lambda function which is responsible for returning content for the whole Angular app and I have

```
custom:
  customDomain:
    domainName: www.mydomain.com
    createRoute53Record: true
```

The problem is that in this case https://www. mydomain.com works, but https:// mydomain.com doesn't.

Question: how to configure something like this in a single serverless.yml

```
custom:
  customDomain:
    ...
    domainName: www.mydomain.com
    createRoute53Record: true
    ...
    domainName: mydomain.com
    createRoute53Record: true
```

if it is not possible, how to overcome this problem in some other way ?